# Authenticating self using StackOverflow API

Tags: support, stack-overflow, api, authentication

I saw the [StackOverflow API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help)

I can figure out from there how to get the data I want, but is there a way to use the API for authenticating myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible with version 1.x of the API.

It's coming in [version 2.0](https://stackapps.com/questions/2701/api-v2-private-beta-begins).